# How to embed Zoho forms in edit record mode in my website

Tags: zoho

I am developing an application using PHP language. I have paid Zoho creator account. Now I successfully embedded the zoho forms in my website to create new records. But now I want to embed those forms to edit record.

If anyone has the solution of my problem please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option available in zoho creator to embed Forms, Reports and Pages. Refer the link below I mentioned here to embed the report in your application.

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/forms/embed-form-report-in-website.html